# Make background darken when hover over image

Tags: javascript, html, css

So i am trying to make it so when i hover over an image it makes everything else darker around it. I have tried using css but doesn't work.

Here is the my code: jsfiddle.net/vkq09wga/5/

Comment: Can you show your HTML and CSS?

Comment: CSS didn't work? Ó.ò

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: everything else? so the whole page?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this with CSS only by adding an overlay set to `position: fixed` and `display:none`. Set your `img` to `position: relative` (so you can apply order) and set a higher `z-index` than your overlay. As long as the overlay is a sibling or descendant of your `img` you can show it on `:hover`:

**CSS**

```
.overlay{
    display:none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7); //opaque background
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

img{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

img:hover ~ .overlay{
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>

<img src="http://www.placecage.com/200/200"/>

<p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>

<div class="overlay"></div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7utvggrh/)

**UPDATE**

Here is a demonstartion of my code with your fiddle:

**CSS**

```
.overlay{
    display:none;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.image img{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.image img:hover + .overlay{
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<div class="image">
    <h3><center>TITLE OF IMAGE</center></h3>
    <img src="..." alt="Image" height="315px" width="100%"/>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <h3><center>TITLE</center></h3>
    <img src="..." alt="Image" height="315px" width="100%"/>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

[**NEW FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vkq09wga/6/)

Answer (score 0):

[Jquery Hover Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

[Jquery Animation Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/)

[Jquery Css Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/css/)

Using this you could animate the darkening of the element by using jquery css to change the opacity and background color of the element on hover.

This fiddle seems to be exactly what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/49Qvm/28/

```
$('ul').hover(function(){
    $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 1);
}, function(){
     $('#darkness').fadeTo(200, 0, function(){
         $(this).hide();
     });
});
```